# Create a dictionary of all letter transitions from a previous dictionary of words?

Tags: python, dictionary

Me and a friend are working on a project and we have been able to find all the first letters of a dictionary with this code:

```
def findFirstLetter(aDict):
    for i in aDict:
        aDict[i]=i[0:2]
    return(aDict)
```

We are trying to make another function like this but instead finding the rest of transitions in each word and putting those into a new dictionary.

For example:

Taking a dictionary with the word `{_steam_}`
and giving us `{'st':'','te':'','ea':'','am':'','m_':''}`

Edit: Thanks for the quick responses, first time at the website so going to have to get use to how things run around here.  Going to start trying the different ways of doing this you guys recommended.  The project is based on making a Markov Model if anyone was curious.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `itertools` *pairwise* recipe - that'll be a useful starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> word = 'steam'
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     print word[i:i+2]
... 
st
te
ea
am
m
```

Presumably you want to count these, in case a pair of letters occurs more than once.

```
>>> pairs = {}
>>> n = 2
>>> word = 'banana'
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     pair = word[i:i+n]
...     pairs[pair] = pairs.get(pair, 0) + 1
... 
>>> pairs
{'a': 1, 'na': 2, 'ba': 1, 'an': 2}
>>>
```

If you want all of the keys in the `pairs` to be the same length, `n`, you can append a sentinel character like so:

```
>>> pairs = {}
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     pair = word[i:i+n]
...     pair += '$' * (n - len(pair))
...     pairs[pair] = pairs.get(pair, 0) + 1
... 
>>> pairs
{'na': 2, 'a$': 1, 'ba': 1, 'an': 2}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for bigrams. This is straightforward in Python:

```
def bigrams(token):
    return (token[i:i+2] for i in range(len(token)-1))
```

Example:

```
>>> dict((g, '') for g in bigrams("_steam_"))
{'_s': '', 'te': '', 'ea': '', 'm_': '', 'st': '', 'am': ''}
```